# How to type this react function with nested / mapped objects?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm new to Typescript and can't figure out how to properly type the following. I've tried using Interface in various manifestations, as well as individually typing properties or a combination of the two, but this only get me so far and seems to raise new typing errors.

I think part of the issue is typing the map function and properties within it such as the nested objects/values.. how best to do this?

```
export function Navigation( { navigation } ) {

    return (
      <nav>
        <ul>
      
          {navigation.data.slices.map( ( slice ) => {
            return (
              <li key={slice.id}>
                <PrismicLink field={slice.primary.menu_item_link}>
                  {slice.primary.menu_item_label}
                </PrismicLink>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) (defined via `type` or `interface`) for the various objects in your props, such as `data`, the values in the `slices` array, and the values of their `primary` property. For instance, something like:

```typescript
interface Something {
    menu_item_link: string;
    menu_item_label: string;
}
interface Slice {
    id: string; // Or `number` or whatever
    primary: Something;
}
interface NavigationData {
    slices: Slice[];
}
```

Then your props interface is an object with a `navigation` property:

```typescript
interface NavigationProps {
    navigation: {
        data: NavigationData;
    };
}
```

And you use it by defining the type of the props your function accepts:

```typescript
export function Navigation({ navigation }: NavigationProps) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return // ...
}
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgEyTQBsUi40IA7AZ3gAUph2RgaADLBWAawBccFKwCepOAHpFcAFIBXTnBgRpANwjAqcJFBxR2cAEZI6EAO6VRMU5nRI4AZVxIYAC1EAczgAb3I4CLgQJFZ1AH1gFxA4ulFJOE5eVkCKSKiY+MSkZIYbOilMoIoAX3JnV3cvVLQPMLyjCpgsnKUVAHkoOAADWJAbKCG4aDh7PxQXPVNwyLBeEEZZKW9o-yryWvqoNxa4ADkUPWBA+eA2ABF5lFDliPZmpHYt94BtAF0auqsFxHRrnS7XGC3Vg8CBgSxtSKsC5XG5sKQIvIRKiPKRglGQ+6PXKRaoApAAD0gsDgmHUrAwULOyIhUIAFCE4EjwajWHBqrjmTyYXCAJTPPJEGDqKC81kvTEAHi5AD55ZjIgr1HRVerdZEQlz8VCAHTYmAoY1vQQfY3rMCs1lWlpigC8yvFes9EUl0tlaq9noVqTgYiQshdISdSGNRmqOoDCbyCp4fAEwjSNOAtioEajxtWoA2toKCSSKTScf9icTkfe+bWReisVLxRSKDKtWr1YVihT-EEInE8a7up7qWHI7gIuJ1eqIs7AZ7WonScUKvl0-2QA)

I should note that the division of the object types above is a matter of taste and probably varies a bit depending on domain knowledge. It's entirely possible to define all of the above with just `NavigationProps`, but it's probably not ideal ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgEyTQBsUi40IA7AZ3gAUph2RgaADLBWAawBccFKwCepOAHpFcAFIBXTnBgRpANwjAqcJFBxR2cAEZI6EAO6VRMU5nRI4AORR7gAcxQYYDYeCDBLAG9yOBi4Vh9-QODWKSjY9LgqQJRU6Iz89jpBJHZc-PLYoylOXlY-BWU4AHkoOAADVnUQGyg2uGg4ewALQKQ9UzyK-LBeEEZZMqmlkCROgH1gFxA1ovFqmFr6yaXylfXNpG2GGzp9w4oTjIBfB5OngG0AXVf8l+O-p7kJAAD0gsDgmHUrAwyS8CQCQTYAAoInF4Uk2HAnlJvL4EclQuEAJRwNKxIgwdRQVhwJHHdIAHniegAfPTygz1HQ2Y90hFmYlEawAHRZGAoYWFYrsYVzMBIpFStBIEkAXhZpPZvLgFKpNLp2qWDKKcDESFkqoiSqQwqMTx5hseDJ4fAEwlEYghwFsVEt1uFM1A81lq3UGy2Ow99q1jqmVqKyoDs2DZzDFyuKBugNjJwZihd-EEInEDpzjMURVLsaJP15TyJ2dzii5VfLzKrNfITyAA)).

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was at least on the right track :) Is there any benefit besides readability to nesting separate Interfaces like that, to me it feels a bit more concise with a single NavigationProps per your linked example?

Comment: @Toki - Primarily reusability and maintainability. I'm assuming these structures also exist elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. That's correct as well, I'm ultimately splitting them off into reusable imports in React.